# ASP.NET Partial Classes and Attach To Process

Tags: asp.net, partial-classes, debug-symbols

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I'm on Windows Server 2003 with IIS6.0.  I can attach to my w3wp.exe process just fine and it even hits breakpoints on any DLL that is NOT in a partial class.

The symbols won't load for a partial class (i.e. MyPage.aspx.cs code behind) and I need to debug that part of it.  How do you get the symbols to load for a partial class and thus debug it while attached to process?

Some other details:  I publish my website (its an ASP.NET 2.0 site) which is with "Use Fixed naming and single page assemblies" checkbox which just creates a .dll for each aspx.cs code behind but no .pdb version of it.  There are other ways to deploy like a single .dll file.  Would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so right after I posted this I tried something and found my own answer.  In the publish dialog box there is another checkbox "Emit Debug Information".  If you check that during publish the .pdb files will then be "emitted" to your bin directory for every file including partial classes and thus the symbols will now load when attaching to process.